# TypeError: X is not a function / X is defined but never used

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting the `not a function error` on `addExperience()` despite the fact that the function I'm using is defined as such. It's modeled off of other functions that work just fine. At the same time, I'm also getting the "defined but never used" warning.

**addExperience.js:**

```
import React, {Fragment, useState} from "react";
import {Link, withRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {addExperience} from "../../actions/profile";
```

...

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addExperience(formData, history);
  };
...
```

**actions/profile.js:**

```
import axios from "axios";
import {setAlert} from "./alert";
import {GET_PROFILE, PROFILE_ERROR, UPDATE_PROFILE} from "./types";
```

...

```
export const addExperience = (formData, history) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    const res = await axios.post("/api/profile/experience", formData, config);

    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_PROFILE,
      payload: res.data,
    });

    dispatch(setAlert("Experience Added", "success"));

    history.push("/dashboard");
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response.data.errors;

    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach((error) => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, "danger")));
    }

    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: {msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status},
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: So what function is not used. We do not know what X is.... Is it addExperience ?  `import {addExperience} from "../../actions/profile"; console.log('addExperience', addExperience);`

Comment: addExperience is the problem, yes. Edited.

I `console.log()`'d it twice: once under the `import`s, once in `inSubmit()`. The first log returned a function, the second log returned `undefined`.

Comment: unclear how it would be defined and undefined in same file. Is something overwriting the variable addExperience in the file? We might need to see the file.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I had `AddExperience` in the `export` and `AddExperience.propTypes` at the bottom. Thanks!